# Trouble creating table in Python using MYSQL

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to create a table using Python and SQL. I connected to the database fine and can create a small table; however, whenever I try to run the code below. It gives me an error

```
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE Housing_Prices(date_ date, year_ int(20),price float(20,5),  bedrooms float(20,5),  bathrooms float(20,5), sqft_living int(20), sqft_lot int(20), floors float, waterfront int(20), view int(20), condition int(20) grade int(20), sqft_above int(20), sqft_basement int(20),yr_built int(20), yr_renovated int(20),zipcode int(20), lat float(20,5), long float(20,5), sqft_living15 int(20), sqft_lot15 int(20))")


ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'long float(20,5), sqft_living15 int(20), sqft_lot15 int(20))' at line 1")
```

Comment: `long` is a reserved word.

Comment: @Barmar thank you so much! There were a few other words i was using that was on the reserved list!

Comment: One of the problems with designing a language that looks like English is that lots of common words become keywords.